# Trying to set background and customize title of a nav bar

Tags: ios, text, fonts, uinavigationbar

I'd want to set a background image and change title color and font at the same time in an `UINavigationBar`. This is the code I have in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller whose navigation bar I want to customize:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar_background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor greenColor],
                      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                     UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                                 UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f]
 }];
```

However, only background image is set and the title remains in the default white with system font. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**For customizing EVERY `UINavigationBar` in your app:**
Move your appearance code to the AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor greenColor],
                      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                     UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                                 UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f]
    }];

    return YES;
}
```

**For customizing ONLY ONE particular `UINavigationBar` in your app:**
Put the following code in your ViewController's `viewDidLoad:` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                       UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor greenColor],
                                 UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                                            UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f]
    }];

}
```